# wc_get_product_id_by_sku() returns 0 for products added programatically via update_post_meta

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am parsing some products from XML and adding them into the database in woocommerce programmatically. SKU along with other data is saved with `update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', (string)$product->id);` and is visible in the back-end. The problem is that when I try to check if there exists product with some SKU added this way programatically I always get 0.

`wc_get_product_id_by_sku('SOMESKU');`

The only way I will get real product ID is if I manually edit that product in the backend and save it.

Comment: Seeing the source of `wc_get_product_id_by_sku` would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't create product with WC_Product object. When I create product with this object it works.

for instance

```
$product = new WC_Product; 
$product->set_name("my product");
$product->set_sku("345678");
$product->save();
```

Then I can easity get the ID of the product by SKU

```
$post_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku('345678');
```